# How to handle Exception using suds in python if the method is not found

Tags: python, suds

Hi How to handle exceptions in suds if the particular Soap method not found.My Requirement is if the method not found(which is entered by the user) program should prompt not a valid method.

```
 for method in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods.values():
     print "the existing methods in webservice are:" +method.name
     try:
        s=raw_input("enter the name of the method you want to scan: ")
        name= getattr(client.service,s)
     except suds.WebFault,e:
        print e
```

but my program is terminated if I entered wrong method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should your program be like this:

```
for method in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods.values():
    print "the existing methods in webservice are:" +method.name
while True
    try:
        s=raw_input("enter the name of the method you want to scan: ")
        #if user enter exit or some special command, break here
        name= getattr(client.service,s)
        #call the target method here ...
    except suds.WebFault,e:
        print e
```

The first `print` line can be a bit more edited to make output message more readable, leave it to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, There is little change in ur code have to add break after name=getattr(client.service,s) otherwise it will ask method name even it is correct

Comment: @user3157084 OK, you can make changes as you wish. I thought you want the program to keep running even if a correct command entered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any loop to keep the user entering new data. Try something like:

```
methods = list(client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods.values())
print "Existing methods are {0} and {1}.".format(", ".join(map(str, methods[:-1])), 
                                              str(methods[-1]))
while True:
    s = raw_input("Enter the name of the method you want to scan: ")
    if s not in methods:
        print "Not a valid method, please try again."
    else:
        break # valid method, continue
# rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: getting error in the second line Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#494>", line 1, in <module>
    print "Existing methods are {0} and {1}.".format(", ".join(methods[:-1]),methods[:-1])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, instance found